# How can import excel 2007 into sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to import an excel 2007 file .xlsx file to sql server 2005 developer edition. but when I try Task> import data i jus can see options for Excel 2000 to 2005

Answer (score 1):

"Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB
Provider" try to select this option instead of ms excel,so that u can import excel 2007

Answer (score 0):

You can set a linkedServer to a workbook file , there on all Worksheets, named ranges become
tables,

```
Exec sp_addlinkedserver 'myExcelLinkedSrver','Ace 12.0','Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0','D:\myxls.xls',null,'Excell 12.0'
```

Note that the Second and the third parameter depends on the version of Excel you are using..(In this case it is excel 2007).